# Adding new cells to the bookmarked table, preserving the style

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx, openxml-sdk

I have a Word document with a bookmarked table. The table has its own style with a font for example, Courier New, size 9. I try to add additional cells to the table, but unfortunately they are added with the omission of the table style. The resulting table has a Times New Roman font size of 12. Below I present the code for which I download the table and how I add a new cell

```
var bookmarkedTable = document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>().Where(r => r.Name == "tableBookmark");

TableCell newCell= new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Sample text"))));
bookmarkedTable.AppendChild(newCell);
```

Is there any possibility that you can add new cells while maintaining the style from the table saved in the document?

Comment: Open a document in Word with the existing table and add new cells. Save this under a different name. Use the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool to compare the two documents. This will give you the basic code required to add cells to the existing table.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using .Rows.Add?

Comment: @macropod Yes, because this is the OpenXmlSDK and not the Word COM object model.